# Method cannot access the sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The following code sorts through a dictionary of words in lexicographical order. The problem is that I cannot access the sorted array outside of the for loop. Well I think this is the problem. I have declared the array words in another method and returned it to a private variable within the same class. But after I sort the array and try to print it out, it just prints out the original array. I also want to mention that this sorting method does work as I have tested it in another class where everything was in the main method. So again I believe my problem has to do with returning the new sorted array. I also need to write a few lines of code within the method after the array is sorted and when I tried to return the array, using "return words;" I was unable to write this code.

```
public void insertionSort() {
int in, out;

for (out=1; out<nElems; out++){
    String temp = words[out];                               // remove marked item
    in = out;                                               // start shifting at out                

    while (in>0 && words[in-1].compareTo(temp)>0){          // until temp is lexicographically after after the word it is being compared to
        words[in] = words[in-1];                            // shifts word to next position in lexicographical order
        --in;                                                   
    }
    words[in] = temp;
}
for(int i=0; i <words.length; i++)
    System.out.println(words[i]);
```

Comment: How is `nElems` defined?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the sort. There's probably something wrong with the way you're invoking it or using it in the other method, and we can't see that part.

Comment: Woops! I forgot to define nElems. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have declared the array words in another method

It sounds like you have declared two arrays: one inside the other method and an entirely separate one at class level that is being sorted. Make sure both methods are using the same array.

If you want them both to use the array declared at class level, don't declare a separate array in the other method. E.g., if you have `String[] words = new String[10];` in the other method, change it to `words = new String[10];`. If you really need the `nElems` variable (i.e., if the sort method can't simply use `words.length`), make sure that variable is also not being redeclared and is being set to the correct value.

Alternatively, instead of depending on putting the data to be sorted in a particular array, your sort method would be more generally useful if it accepted any array to be sorted as a parameter:

```
public static void insertionSort(String[] words, int nElems) {
    /* ... rest of method as before ... */
}
```

I've made that method `static` too, since it no longer depends on any instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand what you are saying, you are using a private variable at class level and that variable receives the words[] array items from a method... in that case:

1. Make sure the private variable at class level is an array named words.
2. Make the private variable (now named words) the same type as the words array received from the other method.
3. Because you are calling words from insertionSort() you need to acces the private variable values, you can't get the words[] array values from the other method, because that array is local to that method, so you must return it's values to some array varibale (the private variable that you must name words), so it's that variable that you must access.